# Webpack - Setting path context for various assets and resources when bundle is created

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-style-loader

I am working on reactjs application and bundling the application using webpack.

This is how I am setting path for css file in my index.html file.

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css" media="screen" charset="utf-8">
```

When I run the command `npm run dev` locally, system run a web server on port 8080 and I can access the application. All this works fine.

When I deploy the application in different environment, due to certain policy, we need to host the application under a sub folder.

What it means is any resource which uses relative path in the application needs to be made aware of this change.

Assuming the subfolder name is `TEST`. In this case a resource which was available as http://localhost:8080/abc.png locally will now we available as http://localhost:8080/TEST/abc.png .

I am not sure what is the best way to handle such scenarios. What I am thinking is I will create a global variable call  `window_context` and every resource which uses relative path will make use of this variable.

so to include `styles.css` not I will use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{window_context}/styles.css" media="screen" charset="utf-8">
```

if I am running the application locally the variable will be empty and if I am using web pack to create a bundle, I will set  `window_context = '/TEST'`.

How do I access the variable using webpack & assign it a value based on the command I am running.

So If I say `npm run dev` (which run the app locally and launches a web server) the window_context should be set as '' and if I run `npm run build` (which creates a bundle), it should set the window_context to '/TEST'

Answer (score 2):

`output.publicPath` should be the right choice, yes. If you want it to change from one env to another, you should do separate builds for the two environments. If your `webpack.config.js` file exports an array of config objects instead of just one, webpack will automatically do a build for each object. So you can have an array of two (or more) build configs, where each has a different `publicPath`.

[Edit]: here's a very simple example of a webpack.config.js:

```
var buildConfigs = [];
module.exports = buildConfigs;

var envs = ['dev', 'production'];
envs.forEach(function(env) {
  var conf = {};
  conf.entry = './entry.js';
  conf.output = {};
  if (env === 'production') {
    conf.output.publicPath = '/DW';
  } else {
    conf.output.publicPath = '/';
  }

  buildConfigs.push(conf);
});
```

This exports an array where all of the config is shared between two builds, except the `publicPath`. Your real build config will of course be a lot bigger, but you can keep it clean by defining the various parts of the config separately as variables, or even in separate modules that you `require` from this file.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I understand what you are saying. Can you please include some example\links to showcase what you are saying.

Comment: @SharpCoder Added a simple example to illustrate

Comment: Thank you quick reply. voting up for great answer and adding example but I think my question was not clear earlier. Now I have updated the question.